# angular interpolation using "async" function

Tags: angularjs

My table has such a code (jade notation):

```
table.displaytable   
 tbody
  tr(ng-repeat="item in itemList"): td
   b {{item.Id}}
   td {{getTypeName(item.TypeId)}}
```

and getTypeName is in fact calling some async sequence:

```
$scope.getTypeName = function (typeId) {
            var lang= CurrentLanguageService.getCurrentCulture();
            var label= TypesService.getLabelAsync(typeId, lang);
            return label;
        }
```

where in service I have function defined as

```
var getLabelAsync = function (id, langCulture) {
       return loadPromise(langCulture).then(function (data) {
                    return data;
               }
```

I have following questions:

1. Do I correctly use promise's data to return actual "label" from my getLabelAsync ()?
2. Why I see multiple calls to resolve the promise (that trigger three calls to server) while I have only one line of table to interpolate?
3. I am also getting

   Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{getTypeName(item.typeId)}}
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of null

Comment: No this is the wrong way to use a promise.  Promises occur async and this should be true of your function call here as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
var getLabelAsync = function (id, langCulture) {
       return loadPromise(langCulture); //Just return the promise that will later resolve
}
```

If you need to make your own promise you want to resolve at a later time you can use deferred = $q.defer(); and return the deferrred.promise; then in the callback functions you can call deferred.reject or deferred.resolve to finally resolve the new promise you created.  You can also use $q.all if you have multiple promises and you want to know when they have all been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you're using promise correctly it should look like this:

```
myApp.service('someservice',function($q,$http){

this.someFunction = function () {
                var defer = $q.defer();
                //do some ajax call here
                $http.get('blah.html',function(data){
                   // pass data to your promise then function
                   defer.resolve(data);
                });
                //return your promise
                return defer.promise;
           }

 });
```

you'd use it like this:

```
 functionc Ctrl($scope,someservice) {
    someservice.someFunction().then(data) {
       console.log(data);
    };
 }
```